# Can't understand TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction lifecycle

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, stream, apache-flink

I needed a sink to Postgres DB, so I started to build a custom Flink SinkFunction. As FlinkKafkaProducer implements TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction, then I decided to do the same. As stated in O'Reilley's book  *Stream Processing with Apache Flink*, you just need to implement the abstract methods, enable checkpointing and you're up to go. But what really happens when I run my code is that `commit` method is called only once, and it is called before `invoke`, what is totally unexpected since you shouldn't be ready to commit if your set of ready-to-commit transactions is empty. And the worst is that, after committing, `invoke` is called for all of the transaction lines present in my file, and then `abort` is called, which is even more unexpected.

When the Sink is initialized, It is of my understanding that the following should occur:

1. beginTransaction is called and sends an identifier to invoke
2. invoke adds the lines to the transaction, according to the identifier received
3. pre-commit makes all final modification on current transaction data
4. commit handles the finalized transaction of pre-commited data

So, I can't see why my program doesn't show this behaviour.

Here goes my sink code:

```
package PostgresConnector

import java.sql.{BatchUpdateException, DriverManager, PreparedStatement, SQLException, Timestamp}
import java.text.ParseException
import java.util.{Date, Properties, UUID}
import org.apache.flink.api.common.ExecutionConfig
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.{SinkFunction, TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}




class PostgreSink(props : Properties, config : ExecutionConfig) extends TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction[(String,String,String,String),String,String](createTypeInformation[String].createSerializer(config),createTypeInformation[String].createSerializer(config)){
    
    private var transactionMap : Map[String,Array[(String,String,String,String)]] = Map()
    
    private var parsedQuery : PreparedStatement = _
    
    private val insertionString : String = "INSERT INTO mydb (field1,field2,point) values (?,?,point(?,?))"
    
    override def invoke(transaction: String, value: (String,String,String,String), context: SinkFunction.Context[_]): Unit = {
    
        val LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[FlinkCEPClasses.FlinkCEPPipeline])
        
        val res = this.transactionMap.get(transaction)
        
        if(res.isDefined){
    
            var array = res.get
            
            array = array ++ Array(value)
    
            this.transactionMap += (transaction -> array)
            
        }else{
    
            val array = Array(value)
    
            this.transactionMap += (transaction -> array)
            
            
        }
    
        LOG.info("\n\nPassing through invoke\n\n")
        
        ()
        
    }
    
    override def beginTransaction(): String = {
    
        val LOG: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[FlinkCEPClasses.FlinkCEPPipeline])
        
        val identifier = UUID.randomUUID.toString
    
        LOG.info("\n\nPassing through beginTransaction\n\n")
        
        identifier
        
        
    }
    
    override def preCommit(transaction: String): Unit = {
        
        val LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[FlinkCEPClasses.FlinkCEPPipeline])
    
        try{
        
            val tuple : Option[Array[(String,String,String,String)]]= this.transactionMap.get(transaction)
        
            if(tuple.isDefined){
            
                tuple.get.foreach( (value : (String,String,String,String)) => {
                
                    LOG.info("\n\n"+value.toString()+"\n\n")
                
                    this.parsedQuery.setString(1,value._1)
                    this.parsedQuery.setString(2,value._2)
                    this.parsedQuery.setString(3,value._3)
                    this.parsedQuery.setString(4,value._4)
                    this.parsedQuery.addBatch()
                
                })
                
            }
        
        }catch{
        
            case e : SQLException =>
                LOG.info("\n\nError when adding transaction to batch: SQLException\n\n")
        
            case f : ParseException =>
                LOG.info("\n\nError when adding transaction to batch: ParseException\n\n")
        
            case g : NoSuchElementException =>
                LOG.info("\n\nError when adding transaction to batch: NoSuchElementException\n\n")
        
            case h : Exception =>
                LOG.info("\n\nError when adding transaction to batch: Exception\n\n")
        
        }
        
        this.transactionMap = this.transactionMap.empty
    
        LOG.info("\n\nPassing through preCommit...\n\n")
    }
    
    override def commit(transaction: String): Unit = {
    
        val LOG : Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[FlinkCEPClasses.FlinkCEPPipeline])
        
        if(this.parsedQuery != null) {
            LOG.info("\n\n" + this.parsedQuery.toString+ "\n\n")
        }
        
        try{
            
            this.parsedQuery.executeBatch
            val LOG : Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[FlinkCEPClasses.FlinkCEPPipeline])
            LOG.info("\n\nExecuting batch\n\n")
            
        }catch{
    
            case e : SQLException =>
                val LOG : Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[FlinkCEPClasses.FlinkCEPPipeline])
                LOG.info("\n\n"+"Error : SQLException"+"\n\n")
            
        }
        
        this.transactionMap = this.transactionMap.empty
    
        LOG.info("\n\nPassing through commit...\n\n")
        
    }
    
    override def abort(transaction: String): Unit = {
    
        val LOG : Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[FlinkCEPClasses.FlinkCEPPipeline])
        
        this.transactionMap = this.transactionMap.empty
    
        LOG.info("\n\nPassing through abort...\n\n")
        
    }
    
    override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    
        val LOG: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[FlinkCEPClasses.FlinkCEPPipeline])
        
        val driver = props.getProperty("driver")
        val url = props.getProperty("url")
        val user = props.getProperty("user")
        val password = props.getProperty("password")
        Class.forName(driver)
        val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url + "?user=" + user + "&password=" + password)
        this.parsedQuery = connection.prepareStatement(insertionString)
    
        LOG.info("\n\nConfiguring BD conection parameters\n\n")
    }
}
```

And this is my main program:

```
package FlinkCEPClasses

import PostgresConnector.PostgreSink
import org.apache.flink.api.java.io.TextInputFormat
import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool
import org.apache.flink.cep.PatternSelectFunction
import org.apache.flink.cep.pattern.conditions.SimpleCondition
import org.apache.flink.cep.scala.pattern.Pattern
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic
import org.apache.flink.cep.scala.{CEP, PatternStream}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.FileProcessingMode
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{DataStream, StreamExecutionEnvironment}
import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.flink.api.common.ExecutionConfig
import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}

class FlinkCEPPipeline {

  val LOG: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[FlinkCEPPipeline])
  LOG.info("\n\nStarting the pipeline...\n\n")
  
  var env : StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

  env.enableCheckpointing(10)
  env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime)
  env.setParallelism(1)

  //var input : DataStream[String] = env.readFile(new TextInputFormat(new Path("/home/luca/Desktop/lines")),"/home/luca/Desktop/lines",FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY,1)

  var input : DataStream[String] = env.readTextFile("/home/luca/Desktop/lines").name("Raw stream")
  
  var tupleStream : DataStream[(String,String,String,String)] = input.map(new S2PMapFunction()).name("Tuple Stream")
  
  var properties : Properties = new Properties()
  
  properties.setProperty("driver","org.postgresql.Driver")
  properties.setProperty("url","jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb")
  properties.setProperty("user","luca")
  properties.setProperty("password","root")
  
  tupleStream.addSink(new PostgreSink(properties,env.getConfig)).name("Postgres Sink").setParallelism(1)
  tupleStream.writeAsText("/home/luca/Desktop/output",FileSystem.WriteMode.OVERWRITE).name("File Sink").setParallelism(1)

  env.execute()


}
```

My S2PMapFunction code:

```
package FlinkCEPClasses

import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction

case class S2PMapFunction() extends MapFunction[String,(String,String,String,String)] {
    
    override def map(value: String): (String, String, String,String) = {
    
    
            var tuple = value.replaceAllLiterally("(","").replaceAllLiterally(")","").split(',')
    
            (tuple(0),tuple(1),tuple(2),tuple(3))
        
    }
}
```

My pipeline works like this: I read lines from a file, map them to a tuple of strings, and use the data inside the tuples to save them in a Postgres DB

If you want to simulate the data, just create a file with lines in a format like this:
`(field1,field2,pointx,pointy)`

#### Edit

The execution order of the TwoPhaseCommitSinkFUnction's methods is the following:

```
Starting pipeline...
beginTransaction
preCommit
beginTransaction
commit
invoke
invoke
invoke
invoke
invoke
invoke
invoke
invoke
invoke
invoke
invoke
invoke
invoke
invoke
invoke
invoke
invoke
invoke
abort
```

Comment: Writing and maintaining a two-phase commit sink is a lot of work. Why not just use the table API with the JDBC connector plus postgres driver? See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connect.html#jdbc-connector

Comment: @DavidAnderson thank you, man! Spent some hours trying to set the table API up but finally inserted the stream data in my DB. I'm gonna write an answer explaining how I achieved it, since I didn't find any articles on the internet explaining it in a straightforward way. I had to search for some updated flink library code on github to find what I wanted. I'm gonna do the same regarding the TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction, since someone might have written a custom flink Sink.

Comment: Glad you got something working. As for the problems you ran into with the two-phase commit sink, I'm not sure what's going on, but I notice you have an extremely short checkpointing interval (10 msec). Do you still get the same behavior if you increase this to something much larger -- say, 10 seconds?

Comment: No, the behaviour changes. In fact, when I set the checkpointing time to 1000ms, only `beginTransaction` would be executed. It was only after changing checkpointing time to 10ms that I was able to see the logging of the other methods being executed. My guess is that the pipeline processing speed is too fast and ends the execution way before the first checkpoint of 1000ms.

Comment: Do you know which transaction is being aborted?

Comment: What I know is that the transaction UUID inside all the invoke calls is the same, and it isn't equal to the UUID of the first transaction opened in the first beginTransaction. But I didn't really check at the abort method which transaction was being aborted. I'm gonna check this out.

Comment: Does Flink table API support 2PC yet? I got no clue from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this topic, but a couple of guesses:

`preCommit` is called whenever Flink begins a checkpoint, and `commit` is called when the checkpoint is complete. These methods are called simply because checkpointing is happening, regardless of whether the sink has received any data.

Checkpointing is happening periodically, regardless of whether any data is flowing through your pipeline. Given your very short checkpointing interval (10 msec), it does seem plausible that the first checkpoint barrier will reach the sink before the source has managed to send it any data.

It also looks like you are assuming that only one transaction will be open at a time. I'm not sure that's strictly guaranteed, but so long as `maxConcurrentCheckpoints` is 1 (which is the default), you should be okay.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your thoughts about `preCommit` and `commit`. But it still doesn't seem to justify the behaviour I got, and here is the reason:

If you supose that every event of the stream takes more than 10 ms to be added in a transaction, then something must be wrong with the pipeline behaviour,
since I didn't make any deep changes in it and because Flink should handle at least tens of thousands of events, what makes 10ms quite enough time to fill one transaction.

Comment: If you supose that every event takes less than 10 ms to be added, then it also doesn't make sense, because there would already be a filled transaction after 10ms.

The only scenario that could make sense is the one where the stream is very short, with only a couple of events (say 10 lines in a text file), and the pipeline execution finishes way before
the first checkpoint, sending the data stored on the transaction to trash.

Comment: The file I used for testing has only 18 lines. As it is a short file, considering Flink's speed it would be processed in less than 0.1ms, but I don't think this is the case, because 
I don't believe Flink would have a flaw such as breaking the behaviour due to file being too short, It simply doesn't seem right. I added my execution log in the question.

Comment: The first block of the file contains all 18 lines, so the OS reads the entire file in one go, and once the data reaches Flink, I'm sure it processes it very quickly. I was simply thinking that there is some overhead associated with opening the file and starting to read it, and that possibly that takes longer than 10 msec.

Answer (score 0):

So, here goes the "answer" for this question. Just to be clear: at this moment, the problem about the `TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction` hasn't been solved yet. If what you're looking for is about the original problem, then you should look for another answer. If you don't care about what you'll use as a sink, then maybe I can help you with that.

As suggested by @DavidAnderson, I started to study the [Table API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/table/tableApi.html) and see if it could solve my problem, which was using Flink to insert lines in my database table.

It turned out to be really simple, as you'll see.

**OBS:** Beware of the version you are using. My Flink's version is `1.9.0`.

[Source code](https://github.com/jlucartc/ExemploFlinkCEP/blob/master/src/main/scala/FlinkCEPClasses/TableAPIPipeline.scala)

```
package FlinkCEPClasses

import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.{TypeInformation, Types}
import org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCAppendTableSink
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{DataStream, StreamExecutionEnvironment}
import org.apache.flink.table.api.{EnvironmentSettings, Table}
import org.apache.flink.table.api.scala.StreamTableEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.table.sinks.TableSink
import org.postgresql.Driver

class TableAPIPipeline {

    // --- normal pipeline initialization in this block ---

    var env : StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    env.enableCheckpointing(10)
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime)
    env.setParallelism(1)


    var input : DataStream[String] = env.readTextFile("/home/luca/Desktop/lines").name("Original stream")

    var tupleStream : DataStream[(String,Timestamp,Double,Double)] = input.map(new S2PlacaMapFunction()).name("Tuple Stream")

    var properties : Properties = new Properties()

    properties.setProperty("driver","org.postgresql.Driver")
    properties.setProperty("url","jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb")
    properties.setProperty("user","myuser")
    properties.setProperty("password","mypassword")

    // --- normal pipeline initialization in this block END ---

    // These two lines create what Flink calls StreamTableEnvironment. 
    // It seems pretty similar to a normal stream initialization.
    val settings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().useBlinkPlanner().inStreamingMode().build()
    val tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env,settings)

    //Since I wanted to sink data into a database, I used JDBC TableSink,
    //because it is very intuitive and is a exact match with my need. You may
    //look for other TableSink classes that fit better in you solution.
    var tableSink : JDBCAppendTableSink = JDBCAppendTableSink.builder()
    .setBatchSize(1)
    .setDBUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb")
    .setDrivername("org.postgresql.Driver")
    .setPassword("mypassword")
    .setUsername("myuser")
    .setQuery("INSERT INTO mytable (data1,data2,data3) VALUES (?,?,point(?,?))")
    .setParameterTypes(Types.STRING,Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP,Types.DOUBLE,Types.DOUBLE)
    .build()

    val fieldNames = Array("data1","data2","data3","data4")
    val fieldTypes = Array[TypeInformation[_]](Types.STRING,Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP,Types.DOUBLE, Types.DOUBLE)



    // This is the crucial part of the code: first, you need to register
    // your table sink, informing the name, the field names, field types and
    // the TableSink object.

    tableEnv.registerTableSink("postgres-table-sink",
        fieldNames,
        fieldTypes,
        tableSink
    )

    // Then, you transform your DataStream into a Table object.
    var table = tableEnv.fromDataStream(tupleStream)

    // Finally, you insert your stream data into the registered sink.
    table.insertInto("postgres-table-sink")




    env.execute()

}
```