# Use postgresql as flink sink, And the connection can't serialize PGConnection by kyro?

Tags: postgresql, apache-flink

I write a postgresql sink :

```
  class PGTwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction 
        extends TwoPhaseCommmitSinkFunction[Row,PgConnection,Void](new 
                KryoSerializer[PgConnection](classOf[PgConnection]),new ExecutionConfig),
                VoidSerializer.INSTANCE)
```

but, when i use it, find the PgConnection Can't serialize,

and the exception is :

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Error constructing instance of class: sun.nio.cs.UTF_8"
```

how can i handle it ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction object specified as a second generic parameter should be first of all Serializable and I don't think it's right to use the `PgConnection` for it. Instead, it should be some custom lightweight transaction state object, holding transaction metadata like id - for example,  below is the example of `FlinkKafkaProducer` transaction state:

```java
/**
     * State for handling transactions.
     */
    @VisibleForTesting
    @Internal
    static class KafkaTransactionState {

        private final transient FlinkKafkaInternalProducer<byte[], byte[]> producer;

        @Nullable
        final String transactionalId;

        final long producerId;

        final short epoch;

        KafkaTransactionState(String transactionalId, FlinkKafkaInternalProducer<byte[], byte[]> producer) {
            this(transactionalId, producer.getProducerId(), producer.getEpoch(), producer);
        }

        KafkaTransactionState(FlinkKafkaInternalProducer<byte[], byte[]> producer) {
            this(null, -1, (short) -1, producer);
        }

        KafkaTransactionState(
            @Nullable String transactionalId,
            long producerId,
            short epoch,
            FlinkKafkaInternalProducer<byte[], byte[]> producer) {
            this.transactionalId = transactionalId;
            this.producerId = producerId;
            this.epoch = epoch;
            this.producer = producer;
        }

        boolean isTransactional() {
            return transactionalId != null;
        }
         ...
```

However, as it's good pointed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59955731/cant-understand-twophasecommitsinkfunction-lifecycle), writing and maintaining a two-phase commit sink is a tricky and very difficult task and it's better to use the table API with the JDBC connector plus postgres driver.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60099987/14058374) is an example of the pipeline writing data into the postgres.